# Using 'instanceof' expression in else if statement gives error "left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type ..."

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

I have this TS code:

```
export class Test {
    public static isMinDate(dateToCheck: Date) {
        if (dateToCheck instanceof Date) {

        }
        else if (dateToCheck instanceof Object) {

        }
    }
}
```

A compiler error appears on the second `dateToCheck` in the `else if`

> The left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type
> 'any', an object type or a type parameter.

[image]

Why does it work the first time but not the second?

EDIT: Adding a screenshot of the "real world" debugger to help clarify what I'm confused about:

[image]

Comment: The compiler thinks that `dateToCheck` *must* be an `instanceof Date`, so by the time you get to the `else` clause, then `dateToCheck` has been narrowed all the way to [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), representing the impossibility of the situation.  It then complains when you do just about anything with `dateToCheck`, since there's no reason to check the impossible thing against `Object`.  That's the answer, but why are you doing this?  Are you handing `isMinDate()` something that might *not* be an instance of `Date`?

Comment: I'm trying to understand whether you are just asking why the error is there, or whether you have some underlying use case where someone could reasonably expect this to work.

Comment: The former.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: And also, yes, the reason for this is because sometimes it's actually a string.  I just used `Object` to make it work for the demo here.

Comment: Well, it can't be a `string` because you annotated `dateToCheck` as `Date` instead of  `Date | string | SomeThirdThing` (why are you checking `Object`?) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxYO8W).  I'm confused about how to answer the question now... you really want to hear "it is impossible for `dateToCheck` to be anything but a `Date`" when you just said it could be a `string`?  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Maybe you could modify the code to be a [mre] of the actual issue? If `dateToCheck` can only be either a `Date` or a `string` then you shouldn't be checking for `instanceof Object` after you check if it's a `Date`.  When an example brings up questions unrelated to the underlying problem then it's probably not the best example (unless you want to forget about `string` and then say something about non-`Date` objects instead).

Comment: I'm debugging code where the incoming variable is a string.  I didn't create it it's coming from other code and that other code has it typed as a Date but it's actually a string.  Like I said, I'm using `Object` there  just to make it not have two compiler errors so it wouldn't distract from the question, but clearly it has.

Comment: The variable is actually coming from an API call.  I don't know how it's possible to assign a string value to a date, but it's definitely a string value in a Date variable type according to the Chrome dev tools.

Comment: @jcalz please see my screenshot added to the bottom.  It might help you understand what my confusion is.

Comment: Is the "other code" TypeScript and do you have access to it?  TypeScript's static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) upon compilation; at runtime, only JavaScript exists, which doesn't care what type TypeScript thinks a value is.  If you write `isMinDate("oopsie")` in your own TypeScript code, the compiler will warn you because `isMinDate()` accepts a `Date`, not a `string`. But that won't stop a runtime error where some JavaScript code decides to call `isMinDate("oopsie")`.

Comment: So in order for this to be a [mre] you need to show how `isMinDate()` is called.  If it's TypeScript of the form `isMinDate(someVal)`, then you need to show how `someVal` is initialized... if *that* is TypeScript of the form `const someVal = getTheDate()`, then you need to show how `getTheDate()` is implemented.  Etc., etc.  Somewhere at the end of this chain is some `string` value which was erroneously claimed to be a `Date`, and that's where the problem is.  You shouldn't have to check `instanceof Date` inside `isMinDate()` if the input is really a `Date`.

Comment: Ah, wait, "the variable is actually coming from an API call".  Can you show this?  Did whoever wrote that just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the API returned a `Date`?  No API I know of can send a JS `Date` object over the wire, so presumably you have some JSON, and the date is a `string` and needs to be deserialized into a `Date` object.

Comment: Anyway I'm happy to answer the question as asked but it doesn't actually solve your problem.  If you want to edit this question to reproduce the underlying issue then I'm happy to look at it afterward.  Let me know.